# Polkadot: how to sign Extrinsics in python?

Tags: python, substrate, polkadot

Thanks to `py-substrate-interface` I can create extrinsics with something like:

```py
payload = substrate.compose_call(
    call_module='Balances',
    call_function='transfer',
    call_params={
        'dest': 'EaG2CRhJWPb7qmdcJvy3LiWdh26Jreu9Dx6R1rXxPmYXoDk',
        'value': 1000000000000
    }
)
```

Then I can also see the `rpc_request` and `ws_request` in [their documentation](https://polkascan.github.io/py-substrate-interface/), which I assume I can use to broadcast a *signed* extrinsic.

The missing step would be the **signing of the extrinsic**. Does anyone know how to do this in python?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment signing is not (yet) possible directly from the Python library, but you can try to pass the call payload from the `compose_call()` function to the `subkey` command (https://substrate.dev/docs/en/ecosystem/subkey), for example:

`subkey sign-transaction --call "0x200400011074657374" --nonce 0 --suri "<secret_seed_or_words>" --password "" --prior-block-hash 0xdcd1346701ca8396496e52aa2785b1748deb6db09551b72159dcb3e08991025b`

You can use `subprocess.run` in Python to fetch the result of `subkey` from your Python code (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Hope this helps!